How to use XML column variable into RTF Oracle analytic Publisher Code Properties
<fo:external-graphic 
src="url({concat('http://example.com/files_display/qr?ids=', 7 )})" 
content-height="50mm"/>

i am using this code to display image on RTF report its working fine. but i want to pass a variable from XML into the URL where 7 is written.
for example:
<ROWSET1>
      <ROWSET1_ROW>
        <IMG_QR></IMG_QR> 
        <IMG_VAL>7</IMG_VAL> 
      </ROWSET1_ROW>
</ROWSET1>

in url where 7 is written i want to IMG_VAL from XML.
How it is possible? i tried following of these as variable but image shows greyed:
1-{IMG_VAL}
2-<?IMG_VAL?>

